# Store translation from ngx-translate pipeline into variable

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a component where I want to use a string to be translated by `ngx-translate` multiple times. Since it will be such a long string otherwise, I was hoping it is possible to store the translation into a constant somehow, and use instead the constant throughout my component.

But when I try:

```
const TEST_STRING = " {{ 'my.very.long.string.deep.in.my.json' | translate }} "
```

it just writes the literal value. How can I force my translate pipeline to work on a string like this?

Note: The language cannot be changed during runtime, so no state is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject TranslateService into your component

```
constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
  this.translate.get('my.very.long.string.deep.in.my.json').subscribe((text: string) => let TEST_STRING = text;

    //or

    let TEST_STRING = this.translate.instant('my.very.long.string.deep.in.my.json');
}
```